# Differential Equation with arctanx

Tags: differential

I have a separable equation $\frac{dy}{dx}$=$\frac{27}{y^{1/3}+81x^2y^{1/3}}$

I separated both sides by multiplying by *dx* and factoring out the `y^{1/3}` and multiplying, as well. Then I integrated with respect to *x* and *y*.

At first I didn't notice that integrating would give `arctan` so instead I moved *27* outside of the integral and integrated the inside as `ln(1+81x^2)`.

Is using *ln* also equivalent to using *arctan*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No;

$$\int\frac{dx}{1+81x^2}=\frac19\arctan(9x)+C$$

By using $$\int\frac{dy}{1+y^2}=\frac{1}{y'}\arctan(y)+C$$

You can't use $\ln$ here because the denominator of the integrand is not linear. Also, the $27$ just means you need to multiply the above by $27$ and will *never* change the antiderivative by anything more than a multiple of it. Essentially:
$$\int kf(x) \ dx = k\int f(x) dx$$ for a constant $k$ is worth remembering

For reference; $$(\ln(1+81x^2))'=\frac{(1+81x^2)'}{1+81x^2}=\frac{162x}{1+81x^2}$$ and you can see why you can't use $\ln$ when the denominator isn't linear.